# Convolution for image filtering

Tags: c, image-processing, libpng

I'm trying to make a program in C that apply a gaussian filter to an image. I have successfully created functions that read/write the image with libpng and a function that create a kernel associated to a gaussian function.

My code is inspired by this one : http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html and it was working for basic tasks. For example, I could increase the red value and save the image. The problem is that when I try to apply the convolution matrice I get a segmentation fault when I try to access the value of the `ptr` pointer. I don't understand why before I could read this value and not now. Also Just before `printf` with gdb I can read the values linked to ptr. Here the segfault with gdb :

```
0x0000555555555991 in convolute (image=0x7fffffffda80, matrice=0x7fffffffda78) at imageTools.c:157
157               printf("%d",ptr[0]);
```

I'm also wondering if making loops that calculate the value for each pixel is the very efficient because it makes a lot of computation and I think it takes a lot of time while in software like Photoshop it is almost instantaneous.

Here is my code :
`imageTools.c`

```
void convolute(image_t* image, double** matrice){
  image_t imageTemp = *image;
  int x,y,i,j;
  png_byte r,v,b;
  for(x=2;x<image->height-2;x++){
    for(y=2;y<image->width-2;y++){
      png_byte* new_row = imageTemp.row_pointers[x];
      png_byte* new_ptr = &(new_row[y*4]);
      /*png_byte* new_pixel = malloc(4*sizeof(png_byte));*/
      r=0;v=0;b=0;
      for(i=-2;i<3;i++){
        png_byte* row = image->row_pointers[i];
        for(j=-2;j<3;j++){
          png_byte* ptr = &(row[j*4]);
          printf("%d",ptr[0]); /* Here is the segfault*/
          r += (png_byte) ptr[0];
          v += (png_byte) ptr[1];
          b += (png_byte) ptr[2];
        }
      }
      printf("R: %d, V: %d, B: %d",r,v,b);
      new_ptr[0] = r;
      new_ptr[1] = v;
      new_ptr[2] = b;
    }
  }
  image = &imageTemp;
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define PNG_DEBUG 3
#include <png.h>

#include "imageTools.h"
#include "filtreGaussien.h"

int main()
{
    image_t image;
    double** noyau;
    int i,j;

    if(read_png_file("test.png", &image)){
      printf("OK!\n");
      printf("Height: %d, Width: %d\n", image.height, image.width);

      noyau  = noyauGaussien(1.0);
      for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("| ");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
          printf("%f | ",noyau[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }

      convolute(&image, &noyau);

      write_png_file("test2.png", &image);
    } else {
      printf("An error as occured. Exiting...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`image_t` structure :

```
typedef struct{
  png_bytep* row_pointers;
  int width;
  int height;
  png_byte color_type;
  png_byte bit_depth;
}
image_t;
```

Comment: You really need to turn on all warnings in your compiler, and fix your code until no warnings remain. For example, your function `convolute` takes a `double**` as 2nd input, but you pass a `double***` to it. Your compiler should at least warn you about this.

Comment: By the way, the verb is “to convolve”, not “to convolute”.

Comment: I turned on every warnings with -Wall. My convolution matrice is a `double**` and not a `double***`. I don't have any warning about that.

Comment: `double** noyau;` and in your function call `&noyau`. That is a `double***`. Either you have not compiled your code as you have posted it, or your compiler is bad.

Comment: Also `image = &imageTemp;` doesn’t do anything at the end of your function. `image` is a local variable.

Comment: I'm using gcc from the default repo on archlinux. I understand now the *** but i didn't know I could write more than two *. There is no limit ? (Thank you for the verb).

Comment: I was a little bit confused with `image` and `imageTemp`. On the second line, is the `imageTemp` a new variable with the content of `image`. And how can I put back `imageTemp` in `image` after I applied the filter ?

Comment: I don’t know how this type is defined, so I don’t know for sure. It looks like `imageTemp` is a copy of the image, but it might point to the same data. If it doesn’t, then `*image = imageTemp` would copy the data form the temporary to the input image. But you should avoid such data copies. Give your convolution function an input and an output image as function arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to improve my code with all your advices. I edited the post with the structure of `image_t`.

Comment: And you were right I got this warning : `imageTools.h:23:40: note: « double ** » attendu mais l'argument est de type « double *** »`.

Comment: Ok. So your `imageTemp` points at the same data as `image`, and writing to it changes `image`’s pixels. You need to create new storage for the output, otherwise your convolution will not be correct.

Comment: I finally succeed to make it works. The segfault happenned because I need `ptr = &(row[(x+j)*4])`. Else it begins at -2. It works but from what you told me it might no have the correct behavior. I'll try to understand better how pointers work. Thank you.